# JavaScript class definition without instanciation

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to define an empty data class in JS to fill it with JSON afterwards.
In c# I'd do something like that :

```
class Person {
    string name;
    int age;
    Person[] children;
    var whatever;
}
```

This doesn't work, the IDE doesn't like it : "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected".

I've tried

```
class Person {
    var name;
    var age;
    var children;
    var whatever;
}
```

but I have no experience with JS, and everywhere I see that declared variables are defined right away.

I don't understand the error since I believe those are properties, and I don't know the behaviour of the JSON deserializer regarding arrays of objects, knowing said objects might be missing properties in the JSON but I'd still want them to be declared (but not set) in the JS object created from the string.

How can I make things work ?

Comment: Although JavaScript is object-oriented, it doesn't have real classes. It has prototypal inheritance instead. Read about OOP in JavaScript on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects).

Comment: Which version of JavaScript do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make it an `object` rather than a class, and then fill the properties in when you receive your JSON.

You should use something like:

```
var Person = {
    name: '',
    age: '',
    children: '',
    whatever: ''
}
```

You can then access the properties of the `Person` object with `Person.name` etc.

Deserializing will be as simple as

```
Person = FunctionThatGivesYouAPersonObjectInJSON();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: No problem, I suffered the same fate when I moved over from C# so it rings home :)

Comment: How do I tell the deserializer that the "children" property is an array of "Person" objects ? Rather, how do I know it'll use the Person object to fill the data ? – Saryk 8 mins ago

Comment: It should just be inferred if you `JSON.parse(obj)`. What's the output? This may be better suited to a separate question.

Comment: How do I print the output ?
`el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(output), null, 2);` I use this to print the JSON as text, which works, but `el.innerHTML = JSON.parse(output)` prints out `[object Object]`

Comment: Because you're deserializing a JSON `string` to a Javascript `object` and then trying to print that. You're effectively saying `el.innerHTML = myObj.ToString()` rather than the serialized version of your object.

Comment: "rather than the serialized version of your object" I have to manually print every propoerty of the object then ?

Comment: Well yes. It's the same as if you tried to `Console.WriteLine(myStringArray)` which would print a single `System.Collections.String[]` instead of each item. You could look into extending the `prototype` of an `object` to print it in certain ways, or give `Person` a `member function` to print certain properties in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the notation used for Java Script objects, so you don't need to store these variables in a class. Just store it in a normal object. If you are reciving a JSON object from ajax request for example you can store it as a normal variable.

So just use that object.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

You define a class of this way.

```
class Person{
 constructor(name, age, children, whatever) {
  this._name = name;
  this._age = age;
  this._children = children;
  this._whatever = whatever;
  }
}
```

To instantiate, you do this.

```
var chris = new Person('Chris', 25, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Precisely my point : I don't want to instantiate it myself, and I don't know the behaviour of the JSON deserializer as I don't think it'll call a class constructor.

Comment: OP was looking to create an object *without* needing to instantiate it.

Comment: Use the @JayGould's answer

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript6 you can implement Classes with JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

So you will have to change your code to:

```
class Person{
  constructor(age, name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Also, problem might be in your IDE settings. Usually in IDE you can select which language version you would like to use. For Example in WebStorm you can select in Settings:

[image]